# drush cex re-creates files in config/sync while they already exist in module config folder

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

Having a config split which says that the location/configuration of the split/module is located under /sites/all/modules/custom/module/config/optional

After it got imported with drush csim our_split one gets an drush cex preview which shows that the recently imported files will be now created again. 
But they are re-created in the config/sync folder.

Any ideas how this could be fixed?

Comment: Do you mean config files that are already contained with the module?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom module which is only activated on demand. It brings it's own configs and they are correctly imported if the config split for the module is added to settings.php. If the module is turned on and someone continues development and does a drush cex the config is again exported to the wrong location outside the module. This happend at least another time but it's not reproducable always.